# How can I get fitted values for a VARX model in R?

Tags: r, var

In order to examine how well a model fits my data, I would like to calculate the fitted values/in sample forecast of a VARX model.

I estimated the model with the `VARX` function in the "MTS" package in R. 
This package does have a `VARXpred` function, to predict out of sample, but that is not what I'm looking for.

I tried Google but so far I couldn't find a function or package.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. Tried to use the VARXpred on the original data to get back a prediction we could compare - only to find that VARXpred fails to actually return its values!

A quick hack to fix that and you can get something - but I think it means that it isn't being actively used out there.

In the end I went to the DSE package, which has some functions to explore the fit and the residuals and looks more like a package with a user base.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the source for VARXpred here, https://rdrr.io/cran/MTS/src/R/MTS.R. I modified the function in order to return the point forecasts. It was kind of easy by adding the next line at the end of the function.

> `return(predictions = round(nzt[(orig+1):(orig+hstep),],5))`

Not sure if I am answering your question but hope it helps.

Best regards,
Paulo

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of VARXpred:

orig           Forecast origin. Default is 0, meaning the last data point.

Set orig = 288 if you have 300 time periods, and check the last 2 periods in sample. Don't forget to adjust the exogenous variables (2 periods in sample, and rest - up to the forecast horizon - out of sample).

(not sure about the exogenous variables, check code)